# Problems to create DataFrame from Rows containing Option[T]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I'm migrating some code from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.1 and struggling with the following issue:

This worked perfectly in Spark 1.6

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, StructField, StructType}  

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("i", LongType,nullable=true)))    
val rows = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(Some(1L))))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows,schema).show
```

The same code in Spark 2.1.1:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{FloatType, LongType, StructField, StructType}

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("i", LongType,nullable=true)))
val rows = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(Some(1L))))
ss.createDataFrame(rows,schema).show
```

gives the following Runtime exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 72, i89203.sbb.ch, executor 9): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Some is not a valid external type for schema of bigint
```

So how should I translate such code to Spark 2.x if I want to have nullable `Long`'s rather than using `Option[Long]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an JIRA [SPARK-19056](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19056) about this issue which is not actually one.

So this behavior is intentional.

> Allowing `Option` in `Row` is never documented and brings a lot of troubles when we apply the encoder framework to all typed operations. Since Spark 2.0, please use `Dataset` for typed operation/custom objects. e.g.

```
val ds = Seq(1 -> None, 2 -> Some("str")).toDS
ds.toDF // schema: <_1: int, _2: string>
```

Comment: thanks for this info. I'm aware that going to typed Datasets it's the cleanest solution, but also takes some time to refactor code

Comment: @RaphaelRoth the only issue is that there is no word around anymore. This is the standard.

Comment: I'm not that sure whether strongly typed Datasets really will be the new standard... I have some doubts

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear which says that `Some` is used when `bigint` is required

```
scala.Some is not a valid external type for schema of bigint
```

So you need to use `Option` combining with `getOrElse` so that we can define `null` when `Option` returns `nullpointer`. The following code should work for you

```
val sc = ss.sparkContext
val sqlContext = ss.sqlContext
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("i", LongType,nullable=true)))
val rows = sc.parallelize(Seq(Row(Option(1L) getOrElse(null))))
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows,schema).show
```

I hope this answer is helpful

Comment: thanks, this is indeed the easiest "workaround" in my case

Comment: great to hear that :)